# Dynamically create a google maps address autocomplete

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, dynamic, autocomplete

This is my use case :

I want to let a user to create dynamically addresses input through a button. I want those dynamically created addresses input to have google maps autocomplete. I've managed to create a single autocomplete address input. Although the input html tag was already in the DOM. I'm using Angular 11 for this project and @angular/google-maps npm package.

This is what I'm doing so far and I can't seem make things work. The input field are correctly created and removed, but the autocomplete doesn't seem to be applied.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

```js
 ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.addAddress();
  }

  public addAddress(): void {
    const newInput = document.createElement('input');
    newInput.id = `${this.inputCounter}`;
    this.inputCounter++;
    this.HTMLInputElementArray.push(newInput);
    for (const inputText of this.HTMLInputElementArray) {
      const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputText, {
        componentRestrictions: { country: 'CA' },
        types: ['geocode'],
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', () => {
        const place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        this.invokeEvent(place);
      });
    }
  }

  public invokeEvent(place: object): void {
    this.setAddress.emit(place);
  }

  public removeAddress(): void {
    this.HTMLInputElementArray.pop();
    if (this.inputCounter > 0) {
      this.inputCounter--;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <button style="margin-top: 10px" (click)="addAddress()">Add address</button>
  <button style="margin-top: 10px" (click)="removeAddress()">
    Remove address
  </button>
</div>

<div *ngFor="let input of HTMLInputElementArray; let i = index">
  <input type="text" [id]="input.id" class="query" />
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe the sample of this google docs page can help. 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

Comment: I did read the official documentation but it didn't provide any help. Thanks for your help it's appreciated though